# How to do I convert an webm (video) to a (animated) gif on the command line?

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, webm, gif, convert-command

I suppose ffmpeg is the weapon of choice but I didn't find out how to reach my goal.

Comment: See [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](http://superuser.com/a/556031/110524) for some additional information.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/436056/how-can-i-get-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-mov-to-a-gif):

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

Comment: I am already testing your solution. Just a moment.

Comment: Wow! It works! AND.. 2.6 MB webm -> 48 MB gif ^^ -- any thought to reduce this?

Comment: I suggest to change your command in your answer to: "ffmpeg -i input.webm -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif".

Comment: **gifsicle** is a fantastic tool to reduce gif size `gifsicle -O2 input.gif -o output.gif`

Comment: Try `-pix_fmt rgb16 `

Comment: Thanks @kenn but it only reduces the file size in this particular example down to 46 MB. I think it is maybe better trying to reduce ffmpeg output in the first place.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino Thanks buddy, but I got an error: "Unknown pixel format requested: rgb16."

Comment: @brubaker I think I got you beat: 120K `.webm` → 2.7G `.gif`. Yes, that's with a *G*.

Comment: `rgb24` is not supported for gif, ffmpeg would use `rgb8` instead automatically.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino will this only work for webm or will it also work for other containers like mp4, mkv, ogg, etc.

Comment: Should work for anything ffmpeg can understand. And you should omit -pix_fmt these days.

Comment: works with avconv too (same command line options). 
gifsicle is awesome indeed !

Comment: To crop the video, pass the starting second via `-ss` and the length via the `-t` option: `ffmpeg input.web -ss 1 -t 10 output.gif`.

Comment: Passing `-pix_fmt rgb16` produced "Unknown pixel format requested", and passing rgb24 warned "Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'gif', auto-selecting format 'rgb8'". If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to remove the `-pix_fmt` option.

Answer (score 50):

[Barafu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/506672/341846) is alright. But, the resulting gif may have color conversion issue as ffmpeg complains on `Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'gif'`. Here is what I find works:

First, create PNG Palette:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.webm -vf palettegen palette.png
```

Then, use the palette to produce gif:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.webm -i palette.png -filter_complex paletteuse -r 10 output.gif
```

Source:

[Covert MP4/Webm - ubuntubuzz.com](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/08/convert-mp4-webm-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg.html)

Comment: produced a much better result in my case than the accepted answer

Comment: Confirmed that this also works on Windows 10

Answer (score 17):

Extending Raynal's answer, here's a script one can add to `.bashrc` to do the conversion:

```
function webm2gif() {
    ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -vf palettegen _tmp_palette.png
    ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -i _tmp_palette.png -filter_complex paletteuse -r 10  "${1%.webm}.gif"
    rm _tmp_palette.png
}
```

e.g.

```
webm2gif recording.webm
```

will create `recording.gif`.