# Recommendation: GUI video to GIF editor

Tags: software-recommendation, video, gui, convert, gif

There are already questions on how to:

- [Convert a video to GIF **at the command line**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506670/how-to-do-i-convert-an-webm-video-to-a-animated-gif-on-the-command-line)
- [Record a screencast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

What are friendly, full-featured **GUI** editing tools to create a GIF from a video?

Ideally, I'm looking for a replacement for the excellent [gifzign](http://getgifzign.com/) which is only available for Windows and MacOS.